# Obtaining the Pseudocode of a function via a script

Tags: ida, decompilation, ida-plugin, script

I am looking for a way to obtain the pseudocode of a function via a script. I am using IDAPro 6.9 on OS X 10.11.4 (El Capitan).

I did locate this documentation on using the decompiler in batch mode:

https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/batch.shtml

If I am interpreting the documentation correctly, it would seem to indicate that I can execute:

idal -Ohexx86:decompiled_output:function_name -A myidapro.idb

and it will produce the pseudocode for *function_name* and write the result to *decompiled_output*. Is this correct?

When I try this, it just launches the text interface and no output file is created. I can, of course, launch the GUI and view the pseudocode of function_name.

Additionally, if there is a way to obtain the pseudocode of a function via a python script running within idapro, that would be the preferred option, but it is unclear to me whether that is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following function:

```
def decompile_func(ea):
  if not init_hexrays_plugin():
    return False

  f = get_func(ea)
  if f is None:
    return False

  cfunc = decompile(f);
  if cfunc is None:
    # Failed to decompile
    return False

  lines = []
  sv = cfunc.get_pseudocode();
  for sline in sv:
    line = tag_remove(sline.line);
    lines.append(line)
  return "\n".join(lines)

print decompile_func(here())
```

This is a modification of the example vds1.py script.